# SP2-1503: Unable to initialize Oracle call interface SP2-0152: ORACLE may not be functioning properly

Tags: oracle, windows-8.1

I have install the Oracle Client 10.2.0 in my windows 8.1 machine. After installation this oracle client is able to connect with the database when we login in as a Administrator into the machine/pc. If we are login with the normal user into machine/pc then we are not able to connect with the database. In this scenario the oracle client application is getting close after enter username, password and database name and press button to connect into oracle client/Sqlplus to connect.

We are getting the below error after type sqlplus from the command prompt from normal user login.

```
SP2-1503: Unable to initialize Oracle call interface

SP2-0152: ORACLE may not be functioning properly
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide normal users necessary privileges to run Oracle client utility, most likely this could be privileges issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this solution and fix this issue from the below steps.

```
Assign the "Create global objects" user right to the non-Administrator account.

1. Click Start, point to Programs, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Local Security Policy.
2. Expand Local Policies, and then click User Rights Assignment.
3. In the right pane, double-click Create global objects.
4. In the Local Security Policy Setting dialog box, click Add.
5. In the Select Users or Group dialog box, click the user account that you want to add, click Add, and then click OK.
6. Click OK.
```

Comment: Login as Administrator account and Create global objects for the required user account after that login as a user, The Oracle database will connect.

Answer (score 4):

For `Windows 7` and up, **right click** on your `client tool` and **Run as Administrator**.